# OpenVPN setup with IPv6

Tags: debian, networking, openvpn, vpn, ipv6

I'm trying to setup openVPN server, but the connection from client doesn't reach tunel interface it's stuck at assigning IP address. From my ISP I get a static IPv6 address (2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64) which is assigned to router's bridge interface.

For my server I have the following configuration:

```
dev tun
proto udp
ifconfig 10.1.0.1 10.1.0.2
ifconfig-ipv6 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::1 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::2
push "route-ipv6 ::/0"
port 1194
```

for client config:

```
dev tun
proto udp
ifconfig 10.1.0.2 10.1.0.1
ifconfig-ipv6 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::2 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::1
remote 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa 1194
redirect-gateway ipv6 def1
nobind
```

for network configuration:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -t nat -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp2s0 -s 10.1.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A POSTROUTING -s 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64  -o enp2s0 -t nat -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp2s0 -s 2a03:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I have disabled firewalls for testing purpose on debian and also on the router. I can see incoming traffic when I connect with the client in ethernet(enp2s0) interface, but nothing in tunel(tun0) interface.
As remote address I'm using the ipv6 address that is assigned by router to debian's ethernet interface, not sure thou if that's correct. I can also ping this address.

Any help would be much appreciated.